# how to initialize a string pointer as a class member in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, c++11

I am using G++ 5.2.0 on a Windows 10 64bit machine. And I have the following code as string_toy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
private:
    std::string * name;
    int * type;
public:
    void setNameNType(int);
    std::string getName();
    void getType();

    MyClass(int n){
        setNameNType(n);
    }

    ~MyClass(){
        delete type;
        delete name;
        cout << "Destructor Called" << endl;
    }
};

void MyClass::setNameNType(int n){
    type = new int;
    *type = n;
    if (n == 0) name = new std::string("A");
    if (n == 1) name = new std::string("B");
}

std::string MyClass::getName(){
    return *name;
}

int main(void){
    MyClass p(0);
    cout << p.getName() << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I use G++ to compile the code with the command `g++ string_toy.cpp -Werror`, it complies the code without any error shown. However, when I run the output a.exe file with the command `./a`, it outputs nothing. And when I double click on the a.exe file, it pops out the following window:[Entry Point Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47jA0.png)
Also, I put the code in Visual Studio 2013 and it successfully compiles the code and the output is perfect.

I was wondering if I'm doing anything wrong with the G++?

Thank you!

Comment: Does a simple hello-world compile and run as expected?

Comment: `std::string *` <--- *you don't need pointers*. The error message indicates a problem with your environment and/or gcc installation, nit with your program.

Comment: Are you using MinGW or Cygwin?

Comment: (1) Yes, hello-world run and compile as expected. (2) If I don't use pointer here, how am I going to use delete? (3) I'm using Cygwin.

Comment: You don't need pointers, since the member variables will be automatically destroyed together with the object of the class. You only need pointers if the behavior should be more complicated. But if you need to use as (as if it is your homework assignment) you also need to destroy "type" variable, since you're using new for it.

Comment: However, this is not the reason for the problem you asked about. I just checked it with my g++ and it worked fine. You should check your environment, that could be the reason

Comment: (1) Now try using std::string in your hello-world program. Does it work? (2) Just don't use `new` or `delete` anywhere i thee program, you don't need them (unless your assignment says otherwise of course). (3) I suspect you have your `PATH` environment variable pointing to a directory with a different version of gcc libraries. Try `echo $PATH` from bash prompt. Does it have any directory before `/usr/bin`?